# ScrollView between two static views?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:float="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Premium Subscriptiondd"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Register with LBC Podcasts"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/tv_grey_dark" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Allows downloads from LBC Podcasts website as well"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/tv_grey_dark"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstname_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="First name" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastname_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="Last name" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="Email" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="Password"
                    float:fletInputType="textPassword" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/confirm_password_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="Confirm password"
                    float:fletInputType="textPassword" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/skip_btn"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/tv_blue"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Skip"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/sign_up_btn"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/tv_blue"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Register"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

      </ScrollView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#BBBBBB" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Already a subscriber?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_grey_dark" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/go_to_sign_in_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Sign In"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_blue" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#BBBBBB" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="Help"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_blue" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View01"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#BBBBBB" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/why_sub_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="Why Subscribe?"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_blue" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

which creates:

[image]

As you can see, the scrollview for the middle content (EditTexts etc) goes below the bottom nav and CANNOT be scrolled?

I've tried EVERY layout configuration i can think of, all combinations of layout sizes.

The ONLY method that seems to work is setting a fixed dp height on the scrollview. Not ideal and non responsive for devices.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be scrolled because scroll view is below the bottom navigation bar. So navigation bar obstructs last few items in ScrollView. Make sure that the `ScrollView` is above bottom navigation bar. Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:float="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nav_bar"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Premium Subscriptiondd"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Register with LBC Podcasts"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/tv_grey_dark" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Allows downloads from LBC Podcasts website as well"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/tv_grey_dark"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstname_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="First name" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastname_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="Last name" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="Email" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="Password"
                    float:fletInputType="textPassword" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText
                    android:id="@+id/confirm_password_et"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    float:fletFloatingHint="Confirm password"
                    float:fletInputType="textPassword" >
                </com.lbc.podcasts.AccountFragments.FloatLabeledEditText>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/skip_btn"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/tv_blue"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Skip"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/sign_up_btn"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/tv_blue"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Register"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

      </ScrollView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#BBBBBB" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Already a subscriber?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_grey_dark" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/go_to_sign_in_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Sign In"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_blue" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#BBBBBB" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="Help"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_blue" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View01"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#BBBBBB" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/why_sub_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="Why Subscribe?"
                android:textColor="@color/tv_blue" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

..

These are the two extra lines I added

```
android:layout_above="@+id/nav_bar"
```

..

```
android:id="@id/nav_bar"
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! I'm quite frankly embarrassed. Perhaps i should have a rest. aha

Answer (score 0):

Change the  RelativeLayout for a LinearLayout with  android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: The bottom nav will no longer be aligned parent bottom then

Comment: set the scrollview android:layout_height="wrap_content"and  android:layout_weight="1"